# Can I programmatically update an editItem in an ASP.Net DataList control?

Tags: asp.net, datalist

I have a DataList control and can successfully edit, delete and update items in it using the built in functions.

However, I am having trouble when I want to programmatically update an item.

If I edit an item using the build it commands, and then click a button that will add a new item to my data source while the original item is in edit mode, I want to call an update method on the current edited item, and set the new item to be the edited item.

I know there is a method like this called UpdateRow for the GridView control but I cannot that due to formatting constraints between view and edit layouts.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, I've just figured out how I can do this.

The link button I use that called the update command can also take a command argument.

In the footer for the datalist control I had a standard button that added the new row to the data set and rebound the data source afterwards. I have changed this and set the commandArgument to "AddNewItem" and the command to update.

This way the update command still gets run, but in the UpdateCommand method, I can also check for a commandArgument after the update has been performed, and then if the argument is AddNewItem, I can create my new row and rebind the datalists datasource

If anyone sees any issue doing it this way please let me know.